# Adding a Table Border

Tags: html, html-table

This may have been a idiots mistake but I have Googled and attempted all ideas (most likely in the wrong place in my code) but I can not seem to find out the code/shortcut/MAGIC_TRICK to provided my table with a border/boxed:

```
<Table bored = "5" cellpadding ="5px" >

<tr>
<td>"sentence" <td/> <td><input type="radio" name="question7" value="0"<td/><br/><br/>
<tr/>

<tr>
<td>"sentence."<td/> <td> <input type="radio" name="question7" value="0"<td/> <br/><br/>
<tr/>
<table/>
```

This is just a small part of if but it is displayed just without lines, so there is no clear table in place. Any help would be great

Comment: Isn't it `table border="1"`?

Comment: I guess it could be a boring table. Are you using any CSS?

Comment: Relic Set, Is it bad to say I love you and yes I am an idiot :( thank you for pointing that horrible horrible mistake out to me :(

Comment: ummm try style="border: 1px solid red;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Table bored = "5" cellpadding ="5px" >
```

Incorrect, You really want:

```
<Table border = "5" cellpadding = "5px">
```

Answer (score 5):

`Bored` is definitely the wrong name for the property and should be replace with `border` if you really want to use it. You'd better not though, since it is deprecated. See the [MDN table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)-page for the details. A better approach would be to set a classname as defined in your css in the `class` property or set the style property like this:

```
style="border: 5px;"
```

The same goes for `cellpadding`. This property is also deprecated for tables.

Answer (score 0):

Then this is what you expecting

```
<Table border = "5" cellpadding ="5px" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The nice and clean solution is to place your style definition in your HEAD and STYLE section of your HTML document. Like this:

```
   <head>
   <style>
   table { border-collapse:collapse;}
   table,th, td{ border: 5px solid black; }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <table width="100%" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
     <tr>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td>&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   </body>
   </html>
```